# Check if product has catalog price rule

Tags: catalog, catalog-price-rules, catalog-rules

I need to check if a product has a catalog price rule and if it has, it needs to display a specific div.

So I need something like:

```
<?php if catalog price rule : ?>
<div>
Text
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't have many rules or many products you can try this:

```
$website = Mage::app()->getWebsite();
$product = $this->getProduct();
$rules = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->getCollection()
    ->addWebsiteFilter($website) //filter rules for current site
    ->addIsActiveFilter(1); //filter active rules

foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    $affectedProductIds = $rule->getMatchingProductIds();
    if (in_array($product->getId(), $affectedProductIds)) {
        //product has a price rule set for it
    }
}
```

The quick and dirty idea would be to search for a record in the table `catalogrule_product`.
All products that are affected by catalog rules are referenced in that table.

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalogrule_product');
$count = $connection->fetchOne('SELECT COUNT(1) as c FROM '.$tableName.' WHERE product_id = '. $product->getId());

if ($count == 1) { 
    //you have a rule for the product
}
```

But this is not the best practice.

Comment: Thanks! But we do have a lot of products, 45.000+. So I do not know if that is a good idea, isn't?

Comment: the second approach should work.

Comment: i will use second option... it better for speed..

Comment: I tried the second option, but that does not work. Do I need to edit something inside your code?

Comment: See how the variable $count looks like. It may be an array or something else.

Comment: I try to load your code inside the list.phtml file, but that does break down the page.

Comment: $tableName was missing the "$"

Comment: is for this a solution for magento 2 ?

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but for others looking, this seems to be an efficient method:

```
$product = $this->getProduct();
Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->loadProductRules($product);
var_dump($product->getMatchedRules());
```

See Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule for reference.